Error - The connection to service named com.apple.testmanagerd was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process

The connection to service named com.apple.testmanagerd was
invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.

Currently I am struggling with this problem while running tests runner
xcrun devicectl device process launch  --console --device '000000000000000000000' 'com.xx.RunnerPOC-Watch-AppUITests.xctrunner

What may be causing the issue?
Thanks in advance
